# designing actions in REST API - when is RESTful too RESTful?

Tags: rest, specifications

I am in the process of designing a REST API for a project we are working on. That is, I am writing the specifications which will be implemented later on.

I am having troubles to think into *nouns/resources* instead of *actions/verbs*. Without going into too much project specifics, we are writing an API around SVN. For example, take the action which commits changes to the SVN server. In our project, we have multiple definitions/versions of the commit action:

- simply commit all changed files
- commit a list of changed files (a subset, instead of the whole set of changed files)
- ...

(1) How would you design the URL? The first question is, how do I describe the *commit action* as a *noun/resource* instead of a *verb*?

Some would say:

```
POST/PUT http://server.com/api/revision/commit
```

Should it be a POST or a PUT? I am not really creating a *commit resource*, so it's not a POST. However, I am not really changing a *commit resource*, so it's not a PUT. Actually, it's not a *resource*, it's an *action*. Once the action is executed, it's gone, there is no resource to be created, changed or kept for later reference.

That said, it must be a resource, so the URL should probably be like this

```
POST http://server.com/api/revision/commitment
```

It's also a POST, since we are creating a commitment. We are not changing anything, so no PUT. Also note that I changed *commit* into *commitment*, to reflect the fact that we are dealing with resources.

Does this make sense? To me it doesn't, it drives me nuts. I want to execute an action, not create a resource which resembles the action. But anyway.

That said, going further, I just created a commitment resource. So logically, I should be able to retrieve it later on:

```
GET http://server.com/api/revision/commitment/:id
```

But there is no commitment resource! I was forced to make one in order to be RESTful. **head explodes**

So, how do you really specify actions on resources in a REST API? I am not talking about the kind of actions which create a resource (create user, ...), but about the kind of actions which manipulate a resource or act on a resource (commit revision, ...).

(2) Then, secondly, in case of the second definition (see above), how do we specify the subset of changed files? Through parameters or in some structure (for example JSON array) in the BODY? Which one is preferred? Are there any general rules?

Thanks all!

Comment: Please have a look at this link http://blog.steveklabnik.com/2011/07/03/nobody-understands-rest-or-http.html.

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes it's easier to back up in a URL design than go forward. It seems to me like what you're calling a "commitment" is actually a *revision* itself. `svn commit` basically means, "please accept these differences from my currently selected revision as a new (child) revision". Therefore, you need to identify that currently selected revision (in order to remain stateless) and then append to it in a meaningful way:

```
POST http://server.com/api/revisions/16/children/
```

That is, POST an entity which encapsulates the differences from revision 16. The server could then respond with `201 Created`, plus `Location: /api/revisions/23/` (or `/api/revisions/16/children/1`, which redirects to the former).

Then, not only have you provided for the creation of new revisions, but also most likely added a useful list of the direct children of a given revision.

Comment: Very useful comment. I fail to understand what you mean with /children/ and /children/1. Could you please give more details? What is the difference between revisions/x/children and revisions/x/? And between /revisions/x/children/y and /revisions/x/children/? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The difference is in the representations. For example, imagine a GET on /revisions/16/ returns data about that revision. If it has 3 children, one would expect that a GET on /revisions/16/children/ would return a list of 3 URI's, one for each child. Then a GET on /revisions/16/children/2/ would return the second of those 3, or, in a well-designed system, it would redirect you to a more canonical URL, like /revisions/58/. The point is to not duplicate data at two URL's unless you don't care about them getting out of sync with different cached copies.

Answer (score 2):

Stop thinking in actions ;D

First of all put your SVN to be file based and not based on a database, that will help in thinking.

If you think about it you only have 3 restfull (well in fact 4 perhaps) operations on your repository: svn add + svn commit to put a new file under version controll. This translates into a PUT on the folder into which you want to add and commit the file. svnroot:/project/folder in fact as the "id" of the file is known you actually can PUT directly on the URL of the file: svnroot:/project/folder/file.c

You want to commit a change, that translates to a POST on the resource (not the folder but the actual existing file in that folder). POST svnroot:/project/folder/file.c

If you want to remove a file it obvioulsy is a DELETE.

If you want to know what revision number a certain file has use STATUS.

Start thinking in terms of what actually is happening, not how the verbs are called (co, ci, add, update etc.), what happening is that files are 'created' in the repository, thats a PUT, or modified, thats a POST or deleted/removed thats a DELETE or the status is queried that is STATUS.

If you retrive the file it is obviously a GET.

So, that above is an actuall existing resource. Now you could start inventing more features, give the file a size and an author or last commiter or a commit message! Now you need to work on URLs, for which no real resource exists. Some call this virtual resources.

Just add "/authors" etc. to the end of the resource URLs and use POST to add an author and GET to read the authors. (Matter of taste, you as well could use PUT, would perhaps be more clean according to the REST paradigm)